# Convert 12 to 24 hour time within a range in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime

I'm getting a time range like this from a field in WordPress:

`8 am - 5 pm`

More than anything I just want to make sure that I'm thinking about the correctly.

I'm assuming that if I want to convert that time to 24 hour format, I'll need to strip out the dash `-` first and then convert each hour `8 am` and `5 pm` to be individual time numbers. So something like this?:

```
$newHours = explode('-',$hours);
$time_am  = date("H:i", strtotime($newHours[0]));
$time_pm  = date("H:i", strtotime($newHours[1]));
```

Wondering if there is a *possible* better way of going about that especially if I'm getting hours for multiple days as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

// 24-hour time to 12-hour time

$time_in_12_hour_format  = date("g:i a", strtotime("13:30"));

// 12-hour time to 24-hour time

$time_in_24_hour_format  = date("H:i", strtotime("1:30 PM"));